# Loop an array withing a String

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I am facing a problem using arrays. I want to loop an array withing a string.

Here is my Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Product: 5 M Steel Pontoons: Quantity 10
    [1] => Product: 6.7 M Steel Pontoons: Quantity 15
)
```

I want to iterate this array between this string.

```
$message = "<p> Name = $name</p>
<p>Email = $email</p>
<p>Subject= $subject</p>"
```

So that the string would look like this

```
$message = "<p> Name = $name</p>

    <p>Email = $email</p>

<p>Product: 5 M Steel Pontoons: Quantity 10</>

<p>Product: 6.7 M Steel Pontoons: Quantity 15</p>   
    <p>Subject= $subject</p>"
```

Any one who can help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
$message = "<p> Name = $name</p>
<p>Email = $email</p>";

foreach((array) $yourArray as $key)
{
    $message .= "<p>".$key."</p>";
}

$message .= "<p>Subject= $subject</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you you can put shortecode in your `$message` like this:

```
$message = "<p> Name = $name</p>
<p>Email = $email</p>
{ADDITIONAL}
<p>Subject= $subject</p>"
```

then get that additional:

```
$additional = '';
foreach($array as $item) {
    $additional .= "<p>$item</p>";
}
```

than put it to message:

```
$message = str_replace('{ADDITIONAL}', $additional, $message);
```